# How can I keep sprites stacked vertically in threejs?

Tags: three.js, 3d, sprite

I'm trying to arrange a scene in threejs where by I will eventually have multiple sprites representing players.  In order to highlight the currently active player, I want to position another sprite, such that it appears above the players head.

I have created a group and added the player sprite and the indicator sprite into the group.  I can successfully position the indicator within the group so that it appears above the players head.  However, when I come to move the camera, the axes appear to becoming rotated as the y-axis no longer straight up and down (see the images below).

Is there a way to counteract this rotation such that the indicator always appears to be directly above the player?

[image: Correct Position]

[image: Rotated Position]

Comment: Have you tried adding the sprite as child of the player instead?